# Data Sharing between client and server?

Tags: client-server, data-sharing

I am new at programming. I am building a basic layout of a project where i got this problem. i have a scenario where i have several clients and a server. clients will be using a desktop C# application and on server sql database will be installed and they are far apart. how can I share data between clients and servers? please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to learn about ADO.NET and entity framework. And use those learning to solve this issue